# Is it possible to detect if a class has a member with a certain type/return type without knowing the member's name?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to detect if a certain class has member variables/functions of a specific type/return type, without knowing the name of these variables (there is no fixed format of naming them).

for example:

```
struct Wheel{
    int wheel_size;
}

struct Bike{
    private:
    Wheel weel_1;
    Wheel weel_2;

    public:
    Wheel get_wheel_1();
    Wheel get_wheel_2();
}
```

Is it possible to determine if Bike has a member of type Wheel or a function of return type Wheel without knowing the names of these members?

**Context:**
I am working on an open source autopilot project. For communication messages, we need to set timestamps for synchronization purposes (Code for setting the timestamp for messages is specified [here](https://github.com/irsdkv/Firmware/blob/04fb3e78a5431b0879e01b54229f7c8e341552ca/msg/templates/urtps/RtpsTopics.h.em))

Sometimes these messages have nested messages and the timestamp of each nested message should be updated as well. So I wanted to check if a message has a nested message and if so, I should update the timestamp of both the outer and the inner message/messages.

Note: The C++ code of the messages is auto-generated from a message definition file.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: no.

Comment: C++ doesn't have reflection yet, and without name, I don't think it is possible for regular class. aggregate with destructured binding might find member of given type though.

Comment: some context would help. Why do you need it? What would you do with that information? If you do not know the name of the member, I don't see what it helps to know that it exists, because you have no way to access it

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way. What real problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one about detecting if a class has a certain kind of a member, but the real problem to which you believe the solution is to detect if a class has a certain kind of a member so that's what you're asking about. Perhaps if you explain what the real problem is, there might be a different C++ solution for it.

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan -The long answer is more likely *not yet*. Reflection in C++26, fingers crossed.

Comment: The only way to do that is by runtime detection through polymorphism of some sort, but even that way you need to know in advance what to expect as it won't compile.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica why? slows things down.

Comment: @TonyTannous - As I indicated there may (very likely, IMHO) be compile-time reflection available one day. There's a study group devoted to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: OK, that "compile-time" bit made me go "phew"

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I updated the question with some context.

Comment: *"The C++ code of the messages is auto-generated from a message definition file."* do you have access to the generator or the definition file, to add your extra method.

Comment: @mamado still no. Define an interface that every vehicle implements, either a dynamic one (an abstract type with a getter of type Wheel that every vehicle is derived from), or a static one, like `std::char_traits`, and add this boilerplate manually per each vehicle type. Can't be fully automated currently.

Comment: IMHO, the most reliable way is to use the message definition file to generate a module able to process timestamps on sub-messages. Lex+yacc (or flex+bison) can easily produce great parsers